# Why does brightness control not work in Oneplus 2 of CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, screen-brightness, oneplus-two

Fig. 1 max, Fig. 2 min of screen brightness where you see no difference

[image]
[image]

Bug hypothesis in CM13 discussed with the authors here: no manual adjustment of brightness when the system auto-brightness control is on, because its what VAB does when you enable VAB's function. 
Thread in CM13 forum [here](https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/128552-system-auto-brightness-on-disables-manual-brightness-control-in-oneplus-2/) for evaluation.

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: CyanogenMod 13
Su: no

Comment: Your OP2 with CM13 sure has a lot of problems... If it has a CM13 thread on XDA-Developers, take the discussion there for better results.

Comment: Posted, I think the app reads the brightness values from sensors and uses it to directly control the brightness required, and somehow feeding the correct input to the *screen brightness* controls

Comment: @beeshyams See the body. I opened a thread about the thing in the CM13 forum for the evaluation.

Comment: Good . Hope you get an answer +1. Realized just now that it is a *nightly*, which are by nature not fully tested and buggy

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, there is nothing else for the rom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the ROM behaviour on your device, but here is an alternative that is found to fix the problem - see [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155829/why-brightness-control-not-working-in-oneplus-2-of-cm13?noredirect=1#comment199767_155829)

[Velis Auto Brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.velis.auto.brightness&hl=en), app description of relevance says:

> Velis auto brightness aims to provide the best possible brightness experience by using your devices sensors to determine the environment you're in. You have complete control over how much brightness will be applied for any given light condition, from selecting the sensors used to fully customizable brightness graph. This is a replacement for system provided auto-brightness functionality usually found in Settings / Display / Brightness

After installing app, OP is able to manually adjust the slider for required brightness

Comment: I contacted the developer of the application with a link to this thread. I also added a comment about the thing in the reviews of the app with 5 stars. I hope to get an explanation why the brightness adjustment can be fixed by the application.

Comment: I am just now worried about too early acceptance because then the developer may think the case is resolved although is not. We have an early hypothesis that seems to work but we do not understand how. This worries me.

Comment: Question for the developer in XDA here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68364290&postcount=1829

Comment: I'm the author of VAB, but I'm not sure what you're trying to say here: if you install VAB, that also causes the notification slider to suddenly work where it didn't work before?

Comment: @velis The notification slider did not do anything to the brightness. After the installation of your app and activating its automatic functions, the handler of the notification slider started to work, besides your app's automatic features. So I think your application must be activating the handler of the slider to the brightness control of the app, which is not done by phone in default configurations. - - This is the thing I am interested in, because it is a bug in CM13 of Oneplus 2.

Comment: Makes sense. On second thoughts, earlier hypothesis can only work if app has root privilege

Comment: Well, the app doesn't have any su-based code. Perhaps the bug is such that system brightness controls only work when system auto-brightness is off? Because that's all VAB does (to system settings) when you enable VAB's function.